# Google AppEngine libraries import

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm currently looking around to find what's allow and what's not in GAE.

Using the [Google's Developers website](https://developers.google.com), I found that _socket C Libraries and the socket module are not allowed on GAE.

How did they disable these modules? Did they performed a complete rebuild of the python interpreter or did they developed their own (like pypy)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to rebuild the whole python interpeter just to disable modules, you can (for example) delete the libraries or (as AppEngine did) or have a import hook that will check for loaded module and have a whitelist of modules which are allowed to be loaded.

Comment: dev_appserver does use a whitelist. The production servers use a hardened (and not open-sourced) variant of cpython, anecdotally. (There is not just no released source code, but not much released detail at all in what they did to harden the interpreter.)

Comment: @Wooble, yes but I guess that at the root of all they just deleted the modules.

Comment: indeed, I had an educated guess on this to.
@Wooble, Thanks a lot for those precisions.

It's too shame that google doesn't build his server as a global apps container and not just as a web apps container.